# Python: what modules have been imported in my process?

Tags: python, python-module

How can I get a list of the modules that have been imported into my process?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sys.modules.values()` ... if you really need the **names** of the modules, use sys.modules.keys()

`dir()` is not what you want.

```
>>> import re
>>> def foo():
...     import csv
...     fubar = 0
...     print dir()
...
>>> foo()
['csv', 'fubar'] # 're' is not in the current scope
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also run the interpreter with `-v` option if you just want to see the modules that are imported (and the order they are imported in)